# Excluding Swagger from YARP routing

Tags: asp.net-core, minimal-apis, ms-yarp

I've got a use case where I want to host both an API and its frontend on the same port. I use YARP to do this.

So all requests to `https://localhost:5001` will by default be routed to `https://localhost:5173/`. However, the minimal API routes (`/api`) have precedence and will not be routed by YARP. This works well.

I'm trying to add Swagger into the mix and I have an issue where the requests for its static content will be routed through YARP. For example: `https://localhost:5001/api/swagger/index.html` will load correctly, but `https://localhost:5001/api/swagger/swagger-ui.css` will be routed by YARP.

This is my setup:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services
    .AddReverseProxy()
    .LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"));

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/api/hello", () => "Hello World!");

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.RoutePrefix = "api/swagger";
});

app.MapReverseProxy();

app.Run();
```

Config:

```
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "route1": {
        "ClusterId": "cluster1",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "{**catch-all}"
        }
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "cluster1": {
        "HttpClient": {
          "SslProtocols": [
            "Tls12"
          ]
        },
        "Destinations": {
          "cluster1/destination1": {
            "Address": "https://localhost:5173/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

What can I do to fix this? I haven't been able to figure out how to exclude all `/api/swagger` routes from YARP.

Comment: The reason why the html work and the CSS not work is the Swagger middleware is happened before the MapReverseProxy. So normally, we will not set the swagger inside the load balance server. I suggest you could set it inside the backend server. If you still want to achieve it, I suggest you could consider mapping the swagger CSS to the CDN CSS.

Comment: Yes, mapping to the CDN would be an option . I would like to figure out how to exclude the entire /swagger/** route from being proxied by YARP though...

Comment: In my opinion, the YARP server is worked as a load balance server and I don't suggest you put a web api inside this application, the better way should be set another server inside the backend and set another route like API to that web api server instead of putting inside the Yarp server. Since even you solve the CSS, you need also solve that json file and there is no exclude inside the YARP

Comment: @BrandoZhang I appreciate your recommendation, but I'm not using YARP "the traditional" way. I'm using it in development to route requests to the frontend running on another port. It's a convenience when using the "BFF pattern" and running things locally. See more info on the setup here: https://github.com/damienbod/bff-aspnetcore-vuejs#setup-development